# Code runs, but HTML content is not added to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a [jQuery Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile) app using the '[Single Page Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)' (e.g., one page = one HTML file), and need to display some ads. However, the ads aren't being shown on any page after the first page opened. I've added some alerts, so I know the code is running, it's just not being output to the HTML content.

Here is the content of my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function () {
  alert("LOADED BANNER CODE");
  // Global variable that stores advertising banners.
  var ads = new Array();

  // Function that starts when the page finished loading.

  // Adds information about the new banners.
  ads.push(["http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-7490208-11465196", "http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-7490208-11465196", ""]);
  ads.push(["http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-7490208-11646171", "http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-7490208-11646171", ""]);
  /*
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  */
  //ads.push(["http://w3schools.com/svg/default.asp", "http://adn.impactradius.com/display-ad/378-10418", "SVG"]);

  // Starting rotation with the first banner.
  ad_rotate(0);

  function ad_rotate(active) {
    alert("LOADED BANNER ADROTATE CODE");
    // Gets the div that will display banners.
    var ad_element = document.getElementById("ad");

    // Prints a new link with image in advertising box.
    ad_element.innerHTML = "<a href=\""+ads[active][0]+"\"><img src=\""+ads[active][1]+"\" alt=\""+ads[active][2]+"\" title=\""+ads[active][2]+"\" /></a>";

    // Switches to the next banner.
    active++;

    // If the counter has reached the end, it shall start again from zero.
    if(active >= ads.length) {
      active = 0;
    }

    // Run the function in 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).
    //setTimeout("ad_rotate("+active+")", 5000);
    setTimeout(function () {ad_rotate(active);}, 5000);
  };

});
```

I'm calling this in the head of every page, so as to make sure it is always loaded. The script runs fine on the first page loaded up, and the alerts indicate the script is running on subsequent page. However, on the subsequently visited pages, the ads just don't appear.

[Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) isn't showing any errors in the console, so it seems like the script isn't able to find the div with an ID of 'ad', or its still adding the ads to the div on the first page.

What's happening here, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: For the rest of pages, place that code inside page div. if ajax is enabled, it loads page div only, and neglects head contents.

Comment: @Omar It just seems odd that it is still running the code though. Plus, I didnt want to have the same JS running multiple times, and accumulating if the user navigated back, as Ive had occur on other occasions.

Comment: `var ad_element = document.getElementById("ad");` will return first element in DOM, that's why it works on first page. If you start from any other page, it will work on that page and wont work on others.

Answer (score -1):

HTML loads things in order top to bottom. You may try loading that script near the bottom of the page to resolve this. I also see an indentation error.

Also, I think you should declare that function before running it, but it is not needed since your code is running. Also, you may need a unique id per page and maybe a document property of what page this is. You may use `document.propertyName=//something;`.

For example, a constant property number and append it to the ad id and then in the code append it to the identifier. Without like that, just ads in the first page, the first ad element found is used every time.

If you have more than one ad element at once, you need unique ids and some way to refer to them and find them. You could also use address parts in an element id and finding it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"use address parts"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Re *"you may need a unique id per page"*: But there is only one page(?).